# Why doesn't the VPN connection work through my ICS host?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, internet-connection, connection-sharing, nameserver

I can set up Internet Connection Sharing on my Windows-7 laptop without problems. (I connect to the DSL modem via wireless)

The client laptop (Windows XP) is directly connected via LAN cable to the Windows-7 laptop and the client correctly gets an IP, Standardgateway and nameserver from the Windows-7 ICS host.

However, when I start my VPN client, I get the error message:

> Unable to resolve the IP address of the remote server. Verify the host
>   name in the Destination field is correct.

I can ping the Windows-7 host from the client PC that should run the VPN application.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm asking and self-answering this after the fact, but the reason I didn't find anything on google seems to be that I searched in the wrong order with the wrong keywords, so this may be of help to people with the same problem.

---

It turns out that you should take error messages by their word. *"... unable to resolve IP address of remote server ..."*. This was a hint that name resolution didn't work.

It turns out that, for whatever reason, the nameserver on the Win-7 ICS host didn't work for the client(s). It was/is routing traffic allright, but as long as the client PCs have the nameserver they get via DHCP -- namely the IP of the ICS-host=standardgateway), name resolution doesn't work. (I can `ping <internet-ip-address>` but I cannot `ping www.google.com`.)

The fix is, once you have the connection running, to go to the IPv4 settings of the (LAN) connection ob the *client* PC and change the nameserver from "auto" to a fixed nameserver. (I used google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.)

Once name resolution worked, I could also connect to the VPN network.